# Alternative solution to replace aging swatch

Tags: cisco, syslog, splunk

We are using swatch installation to sort through 3-5 gig worth of networking syslog and alert us on patterns , we are using splunk to index and search the data but splunk alerting capabilities are seriously lacking.

I wondering what are folks using for similar alerting requirements.

Comment: To avoid getting your question closed as a "shopping question", you should really flesh out your requirements and how splunk doesn't seem to be meeting them. From the FAQ : http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/ " Thus, when it comes to shopping questions, don’t ask us what you should buy — ask us what you need to learn to tell what you should buy."

Answer (score 1):

I have been using [logsurfer](http://www.crypt.gen.nz/logsurfer/) for pattern alerting with very good success.

It is written in C, and munches through logs very quickly.  This is a small [Introduction to logsurfer](http://www.crypt.gen.nz/papers/logsurfer.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can also try [LogZilla](http://www.logzilla.pro) out, it scales to hundred of millions of events and will do email alerts and snmp trap forwarding based on regex pattern matches.